# Why does the Firefox download dialog sometimes lose focus?

Tags: firefox, download, focus

When I'm clicking a link to start a download, sometimes the main window steals the focus from the download dialog. This is extremely annoying for me as I have a habit of pressing enter to get to the "save as" dialog. Instead, that key press will end up in the main window, and typically start a second download, since the download link is focused. This issue is present both on OSX and Windows, in FF 5.

**Why** does Firefox behave this way? Is this supposed to be a security feature? Is this change documented somewhere in any change log?

**How** can I turn it off?